# scroll while bottom of div

Tags: javascript, variables, scroll

I have some problem running a function while "scrolling = true". All i want to do is to be able to run a script, while scrolled to the bottom of a div.

```
function scrolled (o) {
  //visible height + pixel scrolled = total height 
  if(o.offsetHeight + o.scrollTop == o.scrollHeight) {
    var scrolling = true;
  } else {
    var scrolling = false;
    alert(scrolling);
  }
}

setInterval(function scrollNaa () {
  if(scrolling==true); {
    alert("test");
  }
}, 1000)
```

Why isnt the last alert functioning and alerting "test"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a superfluous semicolon after your `if` statement.

Also, you have to define `scrolling` as a global variable. Currently, it's only in the scope of the `scrolled()` function. This may help:

```
var scrolling;

function scrolled (o) {
  //visible height + pixel scrolled = total height 
  if(o.offsetHeight + o.scrollTop == o.scrollHeight) {
   scrolling = true;
  } else {
   scrolling = false;
    alert(scrolling);
  }
}

setInterval(function scrollNaa () {
  if(scrolling==true) {
    alert("test");
  }
}, 1000)
```

(I also removed the semicolon.)